# How to put JsBarcode inside javascript button function?

Tags: javascript, button

I have found this documentation, that generate barcodes with JS ([documentation - gitHub](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode))

Code that displays bar code is:

```
<img id="barcode1"/>
<script>
$('#barcode1').JsBarcode("test");
</script>
```

How to put function that shows barcode after you click on button, i have try this:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Bar1" />
<img id="barcode1"/>

<script>
  $('#btn1').click(function(){
      $('#barcode1').JsBarcode("test");
  });       
</script>
```

But this is not working. After debugging I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Realy thanks for help.

Comment: At which line does it throw the exception?

Comment: this: $('#barcode1').JsBarcode("test");

Comment: my mistake... I found what couse error, It was js library. I have imported two js library, js - 1.9.1 and 1.7.1. User that sugested me to look libraries deleted his comment, anyway upvote for him/her :)

Comment: You're welcome:).  I deleted my comment because I don't know how is possible that first example work if library is not ok?

Comment: @merso0027 if you wish I can update my code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you do not include the library correctly. Try using the newest release from:
https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/releases

This works just fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/jbcx467y/1/

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Bar1" />
<img id="barcode1"/>
<script>
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
      $('#barcode1').JsBarcode("test");
    }); 
</script>
```